# Spatial autocorrelation of car crashes and traffic safety complaints in python

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, moran-index

I am admittedly new to spatial autocorrelation and I did this research myself so apologies if this is completely noob behavior. I am trying to determine if there is a correlation between the location of car crashes in NYC and the number of 311 complaints about traffic safety issues within 100 meters. Below is the code, but the results are thus:

Moran's I for Killed: 0.263
p-value for Killed: 0.001

Moran's I for All Crashes: 0.859
p-value for All Crashes: 0.001

My worry is I am doing something incorrect that is influencing the conclusions I could make.

```
from libpysal.weights import KNN
import libpysal
from esda.moran import Moran
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import wkt

radius = libpysal.cg.RADIUS_EARTH_KM

moran_df = pd.read_csv('../data/model_nyc_crash.csv')
moran_df['crash_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(moran_df['crash_datetime'])
drop_cols = ['collision_id', 'crash_datetime', 'unique_id', 'zip_code','rain_1mm','borough', 'injury_type',
            'injury_severity', 'total_commute_population', 'commute_car', 'commute_public_transport',
            'commute_walk', 'commute_other', 'total_population_poverty', 'below_poverty_count', 'cam_type']
moran_df = moran_df.drop(columns=drop_cols)
moran_killed = moran_df[moran_df['crash_severity'] == 'Killed']

moran_df['geometry'] = moran_df['geometry'].apply(wkt.loads)
moran_killed['geometry'] = moran_killed['geometry'].apply(wkt.loads)

gdf_moran_killed = gpd.GeoDataFrame(moran_killed, geometry='geometry')
gdf_moran_total = gpd.GeoDataFrame(moran_df, geometry='geometry')

gdf_list = {"Killed" : gdf_moran_killed, "All Crashes": gdf_moran_total}
print("Spatial autocorrelation analysis of crashes with at least one injury or death and 311 road safety complaints:")
for name, gdf in gdf_list.items():
    w= KNN.from_dataframe(gdf, geom_col='geometry', k=5, radius=radius) 
    w.transform = 'R'

    moran = Moran(gdf['complaints_within100m'], w)

    print(f"Moran's I for {name}:", moran.I)
    print(f"p-value for {name}:", moran.p_sim)
```